# Issue with IIS on Azure VM Windows Server 2016

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, windows-server-2016

I created a Azure VM in DevTestLab using base Windows Server 2016 DataCenter. Then I enabled web server role referencing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXsVYJUUZ_s).

It seems there is some issue with IIS 10 as I am not able to access default website on this server. To verify further, I also tried to host a website with single html page but same issue "Page can't be displayed."

[image]

Comment: I gave it a try with chrome browser and its working like charm. I guess squid proxy on IE not allowing website getting displayed. I think ideally squid proxy shouldn't block localhost websites. I'll approach our network team to get exception added for localhost websites.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved, maybe we can add your workaround as an answer and accept it:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave  a try with chrome browser and able to browse localhost website on chrome. So IIS 10 seems good on VM. Initially I guess was IIS 10 not configured properly but now it seems proxy on IE not allowing website content getting displayed. Now I am able to proceed with chrome and will reach out our network team if required.